# Hardy Littlewood maximal function bounded in higher $p-$norm?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, harmonic-analysis

I would like to show that for $0<s<t<\infty$ and $$L_sf(x):=\left(\sup_{r>0} \frac{1}{|B(x, r)|}\int_{B(x, r)} |f(y)|^s\, dy \right)^{\frac{1}{s}}$$ the s-th order HL-maximal function
we have $||L_sf||_t \le K ||f||_t$ for some $K$ finite. Does anybody know how to do this? Looks like an application of Hoelder or anything like that.

Comment: Where is the $q$? Don't you mean $s$-th order?

Comment: @tomasz yep...that's it

Comment: Thus cannot be true. If you scale $f $ to $\alpha f $, the left-hand side scales by $\alpha^s $, but the right hand side by $\alpha $. For $s\neq 1$, this yields a contradiction, either as $\alpha \to \infty  $ or as $\alpha \downarrow 0$.

Comment: sorry, forgot the obvious scaling correction

Comment: Do you mean $\|L_sf\|_t\le K\|f\|_t$?

Comment: and also yes to this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f \in L^t$, then $|f|^s \in L^{t/s}$.  But since $t/s > 1$, the usual maximal function is bounded from $L^{t/s} \to L^{t/s}$, say with norm $K$. This implies

$$
\|L_s f\|_{L^t}^s = \| (M |f|^s )^{1/s} \|_{L^{t}}^s = \| M |f|^s \|_{L^{t/s}} \leq K \cdot \| |f|^s \|_{L^{t/s}} = K \cdot \| f\|_{L^t}^s .
$$
Take this estimate to the power $1/s$ to get the claim.